# Override TypeORM Column options

Tags: typeorm

I'd like to create an edit table for a TypeORM entity, where all of the columns are nullable. This is used to propose updates to the final table, and there will be UI to allow users to accept or reject the edits.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make overrides to the `@Column` options to make this possible. What is the best way to express this?

Here is what I tried with inheritance from a `BaseProfileEntity`, but doesn't seem to work:

```js
export abstract class BaseProfileEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public name!: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public location!: string;
}

/**
 * Edit proposal to a profile. All columns should be NULLABLE. If they are not null,
 * that means an edit for that column was proposed.
 */
export class ProfileEdit extends BaseProfileEntity {
  @Column()
  public editAuthor!: string;
}

/**
 * The final profile. I want to make some columns NOT NULLABLE and add a default.
 */
export class Profile extends BaseProfileEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: false, default: "" })
  public name!: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public location!: string;
}
```